# Trouble Converting ggplot2 to plotly using ggplotly

Tags: r, rstudio, plotly

When I convert my ggplot2 to plotly by way of ggplotly, the labels that I create using geom_text in ggplot2 in the step before does not convert correctly

```r
library(ffanalytics)

data<-scrape_data(src = c("CBS", "ESPN", "FantasyData", "FantasyPros",
"FantasySharks", "FleaFlicker", "NumberFire", "Yahoo",
"FantasyFootballNerd", "NFL", "RTSports", "Walterfootball"),
pos = c("QB", "RB", "WR", "TE", "DST"),
season = 2019, week = 3)

ppr<-custom_scoring(pass_yds = 0.04, pass_tds = 4,
rush_yds = 0.1, rush_tds = 6,
rec = 1, rec_yds = 0.1, rec_tds = 6) 

my_projections <- projections_table(data,scoring_rules=ppr)

Week3Projections <- merge(x=my_projections,y=player_table[, 
                        c("last_name", "first_name", "id")],by="id",all.x=TRUE)

Week3WRProjections <- subset(Week3Projections, pos=='WR' & 
                             avg_type=='average' & pos_rank <40)

Week3WRProjections<- 
Week3WRProjections[!is.na(Week3WRProjections$sd_pts),]

colnames(Week3WRProjections)[colnames(Week3WRProjections)=="tier"] <- "tier_"

Week3WRProjections$Tier <- cut(Week3WRProjections$points, 
                               breaks=c(0,5,8,12,14,16,17.5,19, Inf),
                               labels=c("8","7","6","5","4","3","2","1"))

Week3WRProjections$Tier <- fct_rev(Week3WRProjections$Tier)

library(ggplot2)
library(plotly)

p <- ggplot(Week3WRProjections, aes(points, -pos_rank, colour = Tier))

pw <- p + geom_point(aes(text=paste(first_name,last_name, "<br>Tier:", 
          Tier, "<br>Points:", round(points,digits = 2), "<br>Floor:", round(floor,2), 
          "<br>Ceiling:", round(ceiling,2)))) +
geom_errorbarh(aes(xmax = ceiling, xmin = floor, height = .2)) 
+ geom_text(aes(label=paste(first_name,last_name)), hjust=1.5, 
vjust=)+labs(title="Week 3 WR Predictions",                                                                     
x = "Predicted Points Scored",
y = "Ranking", color = "Tier") + theme_gray() +
theme(text=element_text(family="Courier", face="bold", 
size=14)) + theme(axis.text.y=element_blank(), axis.ticks.y=element_blank()) +
 scale_x_continuous(limits=c(0,30))

done<-ggplotly(pw,tooltip = "text")
```

I am using hjust and vjust in geom_text and it looks fine in the 
ggplot2, but once converted to plotly from ggplotly the labels arent in 
the right spot